# Divisibility of a number of the form $4^n-1$ with large $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function

I came across a question which was $4^{1000} -1$ is divisible by ...".

I tried the dividing tricks, but I couldn't do it because the number was too large.

Comment: Which divisors did you have to test?

Comment: lookup elementary number theory questions. not exponential function

Comment: Consider the quadratic $a^2-b^2$ and how it factors...

Comment: Well, there are tricks.  We know $4^{1000}- 1= (4^{500}-1)(4^{500} + 1)$.  As $4^{500} -1, 4^{500}, 4^{500} + 1$ are consecutive, one of them is divisible by 3 and it isn't $4^{500}$.  So that number is divisible by 3.  There are probably other tricks.  We know what $4^{1000} \equiv k \mod n$ for any odd $n$ so that will give us some more things to muck with.  But what divisors do you have to text.

Comment: $2^{2000}$ is also a fifth power and consequences of that won't appear in the factorizations by squares that others are pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Note: $\frac {x^k - 1}{x-1} = x^{k-1}+ .... + 1$ so $x-1|x^k - 1$ and so $2^k - 1|2^{km} - 1$.

So $4^{1000} - 1 = 2^{2000} -1$ .

So if $k | 2000=2^4*5^3$ then $2^k -1|2^{2000} -1$.

So $2^k - 1$ is divisor for $k = 1,2,4,8,16,5,10,20,40,80,25,50,100,200,400,125,250,500,1000,2000$

Note: $\frac {x^2n - 1}{x + 1} = x^{2n-1}-x^{2n-2}+...-x^2+x - 1$

So for $k|1000$ then $2^k + 1|2^{2000} - 1$ which holds for $1,2,4,8,5,10,20,40,25,50,100,200,125,250,500,1000$.

So those are a lot of factors!

But there are more.

For each $k|n$ and $n|2000$ then $1 + 2^k + 2^{2k} + ..... + 2^{n-k}$ is a factor.

As is $2^{n-k} - .... -2^{2k} + 2^k -1$ if $k|2n$ and $n|2000$.

So for example $31 = 2^5 -1$ and $33 = 2^5 + 1$ are both factors as are .... lots of things.  Also $2^8 \pm 1 = 63,65$ etc.  $13=1+4+8$.  ($11$ seems to be a lucky accident as $2^5 + 1$ wasn't prime.) Way too many to list.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$4^{1000}-1=2^{2000}-1=(2^{1000}-1)\cdot (2^{1000}+1).$$

Comment: And keep repeating!

Comment: right $2^{1000}-1= (2^{500} +1)(2^{500 -1)$ and $2^{500} - 1$ is similar.  The hard part will be determining if $2^{1000} +1, 2^{500} + 1, 2^{250}+1, 2^{125} + 1$ etc. have factors or not.